# Datediff in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have this following query:

```
$res = NonRemittedReceipts::where('nonrem_cstatus','<>','Closed');
       $res->where('nonrem_country',Session::get('country'));
       $res -> whereRaw("DATEDIFF(".$getweekdate.",nonrem_created_date)  > 1");
$count = $res->count();
return $count;
```

The result which I am supposed to get is 1. I do get it if I dont use the whereRaw clause.

Kindly help me.

Comment: use `carbon` library, esp diffInDays()

Comment: try this... https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/general-discussion/difference-between-two-carbon-dates

Answer (score 0):

Since variable $getweekdate is a string type you may need to put it in single quote. whereRaw treat sql  where condition as it is.

```
$res->whereRaw("DATEDIFF('" . $getweekdate . "',nonrem_created_date)  > 1");
```